# Can your ammo rack explode if it has no ammo?

Tags: world-of-tanks

In one of my games in World of Tanks an enemy hit me in the ammo and it exploded even though i had just 2 shells left AND one of them was loaded! So I was wondering... Could the ammo rack explode even if it has NO ammo?
Or if the tank has only 1 shell that is loaded?

Bonus: Will the game play the clanging sound of shells if the tank has 1 shell left and the ammo rack gets damaged?

Any answer + evidence is appreciated.

Comment: [This thread](http://forum.wotblitz.eu/index.php?/topic/2188-ammo-rack-wtf/) states that an empty ammo rack won't explode if shot.  Can't say for sure about if you have 1 shell loaded.

Comment: @CommandoAir, reducing ammo load will NOT reduce likelihood of ammo rack

Comment: @panzerquack, thinking of the wrong game, removed my original comment. Thanks ;)

Comment: @CommandoAir its okay ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, your ammo rack will not explode when it reaches 0 hitpoints if it has no shells left. The number of shells in the ammo rack above 0 does not influence the chance of it exploding. If at least one shell is in the ammo rack and it's hitpoints drop below it will always detonate.

> If the ammunition rack's hitpoints reach zero, it explodes, destroying the tank and its crew completely regardless of the remaining hitpoints on either of them. The only case the tank does not explode with a "red" ammo rack, is when the rack is completely empty.You can increase your ammo rack's hitpoints by installing "Wet" Ammo Rack equipment or by training the Safe Stowage perk on a crew member with the role of loader.

Source: [wargaming wiki](http://wiki.wargaming.net/en/Battle_Mechanics#Module_and_Crew_Damage)

Comment: What if the tank has a single shell that is loaded? Does it still count as explodable?

Comment: I'm pretty sure having a shell in the gun will still have the ammo rack explode. I don't have a source for that though.